# Meteor App Management

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to use PM2 to manage Meteor APPs, because I have multi Meteor APPs on my server. So it will be very helpful if I can start or restart them by PM2.

I googled this question and found several answers about this issue.
But I can't use PM2 for Meteor successfully.
I'm not sure why.

Does someone else is using PM2 to manage Meteor APPs?
Any suggestion about how to manage Meteor APPs would be very appreciate!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should deploy your app with `meteor build bundle` and then install it with node

since this way you run `node main.js` to run the Meteor project, you should be able to use pm2 as usual with a node server:

`pm2 start main.js`

see questions like: [Why do we need to deploy a meteor app instead of just starting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385669/why-do-we-need-to-deploy-a-meteor-app-instead-of-just-starting-it?answertab=votes#tab-top)  for more info on how to deploy.